# Why do I get runtime error DBSQL_DBSL_LENGTH_ERROR?

Tags: abap

I have the following code:

```
DATA: lt_matnr TYPE TABLE OF mara,
      ls_matnr TYPE mara,
      lv_werk TYPE werks_d VALUE 'WERK',
      lt_stoc_int TYPE TABLE OF zmm_s_stock_list,
      lt_stoc TYPE TABLE OF zsd_stock_list,
      ls_stoc TYPE zsd_stock_list.

  SELECT matnr
    FROM mara
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_matnr.

  LOOP AT lt_matnr INTO ls_matnr.

    CALL FUNCTION 'Z_MM_LIST_STOC_MATERIAL_WERKS'
      EXPORTING
        IP_MATNR           = ls_matnr-matnr
        IP_WERKS           = lv_werk
     IMPORTING
       ET_STOCK_EXP       = lt_stoc_int.

    LOOP AT lt_stoc_int ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_stoc_int>).

      MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_stoc_int> TO ls_stoc.

*      + other data processing ...

      APPEND ls_stoc TO lt_stoc.

    ENDLOOP.

  ENDLOOP.

  INSERT zsd_stock_list FROM TABLE lt_stoc.
```

Everything works fine until the INSERT statement where I get the following short-dump:

Runtime error: DBSQL_DBSL_LENGTH_ERROR

Exception: CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB

Error analysis:
An exception has occurred which is explained in more detail below. The
exception, which is assigned to class 'CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB' was not caught an
therefore caused a runtime error. ***The reason for the exception is:
While accessing a database, the length of a field in ABAP does not
match the size of the corresponding database field.***
This can happen for example if a string is bound to a database field
that is shorter than the current string.

It makes little sense because `lt_stoc` is `TYPE TABLE OF zsd_stock_list`, how can the field length not match ?

Comment: Do you have one of the table columns defined as DEC/QUAN/CURR with an even length (2, 4, 6, ...)? SAP highly recommends to define an odd length (1, 3, 5, ...)

Comment: I do have 2 fields TYPE QUAN with data elements MNG06 and LFIMG and they both have length 13 with decimal places 3.

Comment: I read that in [HANA note 2399990](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2399990): `This error happens when ABAP uses a string with a size larger than the corresponding field size on database side. Make sure that the database field size is sufficiently sized to hold all possible values. Several SAP Notes exist that describe known issues that can result in this short dump in different areas.`

Comment: `SAP highly recommends to define an odd length (1, 3, 5, ...)` where this recommendation is described?

Comment: I have sorted the internal table and deleted the duplicates and (for now) the error does not occur any more. So, at the moment, I'm just keeping my fingers crossed that it doesn't happen again.

Comment: yep, the main thing while debugging such errors is to analyze test data on which the error occurs, and you didn't provide any data in your question

Comment: I can't really provide system data, because it is confidential. In the quality system it worked just fine inserting 400k data and in productive system it generated a short dump while inserting 500k data (before deleting duplicates). It is possible that the error was generated by duplicate data, but if so, then why did I got this error ( DBSQL_DBSL_LENGTH_ERROR ) ? I inserted duplicate data in debug and got the following error: DBSQL_DUPLICATE_KEY_ERROR